# GCP Cloud Sql (Postgres) simple select queries exceed disk read quota

Tags: io, google-cloud-sql, disk, quota

I am using GCP Cloud Sql (Postgress), I am experiencing a very weird behaviour, I am connecting to Cloud Sql via a Springboot application and sending concurrent select queries to Cloud Sql,

I noticed very high read disk operations for simple select queries, I am just wondering for a simple select query, how many disk I/O will be done roughly? How we can find the bottleneck in this scenario?

I also have done explain analyse for each query and for all of them an index scan has been triggered, I also have a mix of tables in term of size, some are smaller some are bigger,

I also have increased the disk size, memory and cpu, but because still the number of disk read operations per query is very high, I immediately reach the READ quota again,

Any idea how to reduce the number of disk I/O while reading?

Many thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You have provided no details on the SQL instance size, database, table structure or the SQL query. In general, if you want to minimize disk reads, either the SQL query must be optimized, the tables must be optimized (indexes) or you need enough memory to fit the database into memory.